# .validate() not working JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a problem regarding in validation in html. I'm using .validate() of the validation plugin but its not working to me. can someone help me from my problem? I have two names in each of my . An array of data i used in inserting in database. Is it conflict? what should I do since it is required that we need to use array in inserting data to the database? I already try to put "#" and "data[0]" in my rules to look for the  but still not worked.

Note: the validation.js served as my validation plugin which i've downloaded online. jQuery Validation Plugin 1.11.1. And the jquery.js served as JQuery 1.8.3.

Here's my code.

```
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="loginBouncy.js"></script>
<script src="modal.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="validation.js"></script>
<script src="validate.js"></script>

<form id="mainform" name="mainform" method="post" action="SignUp2.php">
<input type="text" name="data[]" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name"/>
<input type="text" name="data[]" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name"/>
<input type="text" name="data[]" id="mname" name="mname" placeholder="M.I."/>
<input type="text" name="data[]" id="sadd"  name="sadd" placeholder="Street"/>
<input type="text" name="data[]" id="tadd"  name="tadd" placeholder="Town/City"/>
<input type="text" name="data[]" id="padd"  name="padd" placeholder="Province/State"/>
<input type="text" name="data[]" id="user2" name="user2" placeholder="Your Username"/>
<input type="password" name="data[]" id="pass2" name="pass2" placeholder="Your Password">
<input id="captcha" name="captcha" type="text" name="captcha" placeholder="Insert Captcha">
<img id="imgcaptcha" src="captcha.php" /><br>
<input type="text" name="data[]" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email"/>
<input type="button" id="btnSignUp"  placeholder="" onclick=""/>
</input>
<p id="confirm" style="font-size:15pt; position:absolute; top:450px; left:850px; ">dfgfdgdf</p>

</form>
</html>
```

my **validate.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#btnSignUp').click(function(){
$('#mainform').validate({
    rules:
    {
        fname:
        {
            required: true,
            minlength: 7
        }
    },
    success: function(){
    alert("valid");
    }

});
});
});
```

Comment: why  `onclick=""` is attaching in input tag, first remove it and see what happends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems.

The validator uses name of the input field, you have 2 name attributes in the input field remove `name="data[]"`, it should be like `<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" />`

The validation is automatically applied on form submit event so change `btnSignUp` to `type="submit"`

```
<input type="submit" id="btnSignUp" placeholder="" value="Sign Up" />
```

Also the validate framework should be initialized on dom ready, not in a click handler

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#mainform').validate({
        rules: {
            fname: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 7
            }
        },
        success: function () {
            alert("valid");
        }

    });
    $('#btnSignUp').click(function () {

    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CwZ8p/)